# Supervisord sometimes starts celery, sometimes not

Tags: kubernetes, celery, supervisord

I'm deploying my flask api on Kubernetes. The executed command when the container is started is the following:

```
supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf 
gunicorn wsgi:app --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 1 --threads 12 --log-level=warning --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn-access.log --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn-error.log
```

You see above that I'm starting celery first with supervisor and after that I'm running the gunicorn server. Content of celery.conf:

```
[supervisord]
logfile = /tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes = 50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel = info
pidfile = /tmp/supervisord.pid
nodaemon = false
minfds = 1024
minprocs = 200
umask = 022
identifier = supervisor
directory = /tmp
nocleanup = true
[program:celery]
directory = /mydir/app
command = celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug
```

When logged into my pods I can see that sometimes the process of starting celery is working (example in pod 1):

```
> more /tmp/supervisord.log
2021-06-08 18:19:46,460 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2021-06-08 18:19:46,462 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2021-06-08 18:19:46,462 INFO set current directory: '/tmp'
2021-06-08 18:19:46,463 INFO supervisord started with pid 9
2021-06-08 18:19:47,469 INFO spawned: 'celery' with pid 15
2021-06-08 18:19:48,470 INFO success: celery entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

Sometimes it's not (in pod 2):

```
> more /tmp/supervisord.log
2021-06-08 18:19:42,979 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2021-06-08 18:19:42,988 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2021-06-08 18:19:42,988 INFO set current directory: '/tmp'
2021-06-08 18:19:42,989 INFO supervisord started with pid 9
2021-06-08 18:19:43,992 INFO spawned: 'celery' with pid 11
2021-06-08 18:19:44,994 INFO success: celery entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
>>>> 2021-06-08 18:19:58,642 INFO exited: celery (exit status 2; expected) <<<<<HERE
```

In my pod 1, a ps command shows the following:

```
> ps aux | grep celery
root          9  0.0  0.0  55308 16376 ?        Ss   18:45   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -c         /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf
root         23  2.2  0.8 2343684 352940 ?      S    18:45   0:05 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug
root         37  0.0  0.5 2341860 208716 ?      S    18:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug
root         38  0.0  0.5 2341864 208716 ?      S    18:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug
root         39  0.0  0.5 2341868 208716 ?      S    18:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug
root         40  0.0  0.5 2341872 208724 ?      S    18:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug
root         41  0.0  0.5 2341876 208728 ?      S    18:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug
root         42  0.0  0.5 2341880 208728 ?      S    18:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug
root         43  0.0  0.5 2341884 208736 ?      S    18:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug
root         44  0.0  0.5 2342836 211384 ?      S    18:46   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug
```

In my pod 2, I can see that supervisord/celery process is still there but I don't have all the individual /usr/local/bin/celery processes that I have in pod 1:

```
> ps aux | grep celery
root          9  0.0  0.0  55308 16296 ?        Ss   18:19   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf
```

This behavior is not always the same. Sometimes when pods are restarted the two succeed to launch celery, sometimes none of them succeed. In this last scenario if I make a request to my API that is supposed to launch a celery task, I can see on my broker console (RabbitMQ) that a task is created but there is no message "activity" and nothing is written is my database table (the end result of my celery task).

If I start celery manually in my pods:

```
celery -A celery_worker.celery worker --loglevel=debug
```

everything works.

What could explain such a behavior?

Comment: A more typical best practice would be to launch only one process in a container, without supervisord.  Then you could separately deploy, upgrade, and scale the Web servers and the Celery workers, and you could use Kubernetes's native functionality to monitor and restart the individual processes.

Comment: You're certainly right and I wanted to do that at first. But I am not sure it is possible as celery needs my app to start. I think that they must run on the same pod. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You don't need celery in your app container. Yes, celery will need your app but you can use the exact same image and run in a different container. Just change the entrypoint or cmd to run celery instead of gunicorn

Comment: I'll give it a try right now. Is it true to say that celery container does not have to be the exact same image but can contain only the strict minimum to make the create_app functional (plus the celery tasks of course) ?

Comment: I would think so, but I cannot say for certain. In my usage, I have always just used the exact same image.

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments above, the best solution is to have two containers, the first having the entrypoint `gunicorn` and the other `celery celery-worker`. If the second is the same image as the first it works very well and I can scale on Kubernetes each container independently. The only thing is that the code sourcing is more difficult, each time I make a code change on the first I must apply the same changes manually on the second, maybe there is a better way to address this specific issue of the code sourcing.